# Ubuntu crashes due to read-heavy operations/high SSD temperatures

Tags: ssd, overheating, temperature

For a few days, I've noticed that my Ubuntu-based machine has started to freeze while performing read-intensive operations. The freezing, however, does not occur during write-intensive operations. Every time the device freezes, I manually plug off the power chord and shut the machine down forcefully; else, the laptop will stay frozen.

I monitored what happens to my SSD when I perform read-intensive operations using `hardinfo` and found out that my SSD sometimes goes over 70 degrees Celcius. The computer becomes unreliable at any SSD temperature above 60 degrees Celcius, and I've had crashes occur at temperatures as low as 62 degrees Celcius. I have tried the following solutions to solve this issue:

- `sudo fsck -y /dev/nvme0n1p3` to fix any file-system errors on partition three of my SSD (which is where all the data resides), but that didn't solve anything.
- I've also tried opening up my laptop chassis and cleaning any dust preventing airflow to the machine. That didn't seem to work as well.

I have seen SSDs reach 80+ degrees Celcius, which, although harmful to the longevity of the SSD, doesn't result in a crash. I think that when my system freezes, the SSD puts itself into read-only mode because all icons cease to show up a few seconds before the entire machine freezes.

How do I fix this problem?

**EDIT:**

This is the output of `sudo smartctl -i /dev/nvme0n1`:

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.17.15-76051715-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       SAMSUNG MZVLB1T0HBLR-000L2
Serial Number:                      S4DZNX0N709811
Firmware Version:                   3L1QEXF7
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 1,024,209,543,168 [1.02 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      4
NVMe Version:                       1.3
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          1,024,209,543,168 [1.02 TB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            373,319,507,968 [373 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            002538 8701d0c0a0
Local Time is:                      Tue Jul 12 16:10:52 2022 IST
```

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Ubuntu based systems are off-topic here, only Ubuntu is on-topic*

Comment: This sounds more like a hardware issue than an Ubuntu one. If you have a circulating fan, point that at the notebook during the peak operations in order to keep it cool. If you’re not actively typing at that time, prop the notebook up like a tent so that it has better airflow 

Comment: @matigo - I'm using a cooling pad to cool the laptop actively. It could be a hardware issue, but why the 60-degree cutoff point?

Comment: @divinorum because your SSD is broken(ish)? The "icons turning blank and then system crashes" issue sounds exactly like what would happen when I was running off an external SSD and it got disconnected for some reason. Possibly the entire SSD shuts down/crashes when it overheats.

Comment: If it's still within warranty or something you can try to get it replaced, but it very much sounds like a hardware issue (or at least an SSD firmware issue, maybe see if there is updated firmware for your SSD)

Comment: @Esther That could be the case. Unfortunately, my SSD isn't covered by warranty anymore. I'll check the SSD firmware to see if that fixes things. Thanks!

Comment: Mine, including very old laptop to a semi old workstation work like a healthy horse.